# Can't convert time to mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 7 columns:

```
Start_hour | Start_minute | Start_second | End_hour | End_minute | end_second | date
```

My task is to sum the differences between start and end times on current day. And my query already does that. Sadly I need the output to be in minutes:seconds only. For Example the total sum of time differences is 2 hour 26 minutes and 52 seconds.

I need my output to like this:

```
126:52
```

My query right now looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(8), 
          DATEADD(SECOND, 
                  SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
                               Timefromparts(start_hour, start_minute, start_second, 0, 0), 
                               Timefromparts(end_hour, end_minute, end_second, 0, 0))
                 ), 0), 108), 5) 
FROM   
    opoznienia 
WHERE  
    YEAR(data) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(data) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    AND DAY(data) = DAY(GETDATE())
```

Sample data:

```
Start_hour | Start_minute | Start_second | End_hour | End_minute | end_second | date
10  15  0   10   30   30   2018-11-27 14:40:53.680
10  15  0   10   30   30   2018-11-30 10:16:20.610
6   10  30  6    23   45   2018-12-02 01:00:27.243
8   10  0   8    53   45   2018-12-02 14:42:48.663
10  5   13  10   55   23   2018-12-02 14:53:03.560
```

Output of the query above:

```
47:13 (without RIGHT command it would be 01:47:13)
```

The wanted output:

```
107:13
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be great. :)

Comment: Start by using `datetime` data type instead of separated fields

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I wish I could, database is not mine and I can't modify it ;/

Comment: How does one minute and one second get formatted?  Would it be `1:1`, `01:01`, or something else?

Comment: 01:01 @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Then as larnu said show us sample data current and expected output. And your table doesnt have data column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the number of seconds and then format it as you want. From number of seconds you can calculate the minutes as division by 60, where the remainder are the seconds:

```
declare @NumberOfSeconds int = 7612
-- Returns 126:52
select concat(@NumberOfSeconds / 60, ':', FORMAT(@NumberOfSeconds % 60, 'D2'))
```

Comment: I'd use a different function to `FORMAT`; it is awfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT
    numSeconds,
    CASE WHEN numSeconds / 60 <= 100
         THEN RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), numSeconds / 60), 2)
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), numSeconds / 60) END
         + ':' +
    CASE WHEN numSeconds / 60 <= 100
         THEN RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), numSeconds % 60), 2)
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), numSeconds % 60) END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

The ugliness in the code has to do with that you expect a minimum of two digits for the minute and second components.  So, we have to pad each component with zeroes in the case where minutes or seconds happens to be just a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  StartHour INT,
  StartMinute INT,
  StartSecond INT,
  EndHour INT,
  EndMinute INT,
  EndSecond INT,
  [Date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(10,  15,  0 ,  10,   30,   30, '2018-11-27'),   
(10,  15,  0 ,  10,   30,   30, '2018-11-30'),   
(6 ,  10,  30,  6 ,   23,   45, '2018-12-02'),   
(8 ,  10,  0 ,  8 ,   53,   45, '2018-12-02'),   
(10,  5 ,  13,  10,   55,   23, '2018-12-02');

SELECT *,

       CAST(  (DATEDIFF(Hour, StartTime, EndTime) * 60) +
              (DATEDIFF(Minute, StartTime, EndTime) % 60) AS VARCHAR
           ) + ':' +
       CAST(DATEDIFF(Second, StartTime, EndTime) % 60 AS VARCHAR)
FROM
(
  SELECT [Date],
         TIMEFROMPARTS(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSecond, 0, 0) StartTime,
         TIMEFROMPARTS(EndHour, EndMinute, EndSecond, 0, 0) EndTime
  FROM T
) TT
```

You can also `SUM()` and `GROUP BY [Date]` if you want to.

```
SELECT [Date],
       CAST(  SUM( (DATEDIFF(Hour, StartTime, EndTime) * 60) +
                   (DATEDIFF(Minute, StartTime, EndTime) % 60)
                 ) AS VARCHAR
           ) + ':' +
       CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(Second, StartTime, EndTime) % 60) AS VARCHAR)
FROM
(
  SELECT [Date],
         TIMEFROMPARTS(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSecond, 0, 0) StartTime,
         TIMEFROMPARTS(EndHour, EndMinute, EndSecond, 0, 0) EndTime
  FROM T
) TT
GROUP BY [Date]
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89bfed0c1e957055674505912184f5a4)**

---

*UPDATE*

It seems like you are looking for

```
SELECT [Date],
       CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(Second, StartTime, EndTime)) / 60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' +
       CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(Second, StartTime, EndTime)) % 60 AS VARCHAR) [MM:SS]
FROM
(
  SELECT [Date],
         TIMEFROMPARTS(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSecond, 0, 0) StartTime,
         TIMEFROMPARTS(EndHour, EndMinute, EndSecond, 0, 0) EndTime
  FROM T
) TT
GROUP BY [Date];
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------------------+--------+
|        Date         | MM:SS  |
+---------------------+--------+
| 27/11/2018 00:00:00 | 15:30  |
| 30/11/2018 00:00:00 | 15:30  |
| 02/12/2018 00:00:00 | 107:10 |
+---------------------+--------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce9921d46fab60daaddaa99b492aa7f4)**

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are better, but to understand what may be missing in what you're trying to do - you can look at following where DatePart is used.
-->"

> ..(without RIGHT command it would be 01:47:13)

"  This is your clue that you that you need to work with the parts and not the whole...

```
SELECT Cast
(
Datepart
(
hour,
DATEADD(second,sum(datediff(second, 
TIMEFROMPARTS ( Start_hour, Start_minute, Start_second, 0, 0), 
TIMEFROMPARTS ( End_hour, End_minute, End_second, 0, 0))),0)
) * 60 
+
Datepart
(
minute,
DATEADD(second,sum(datediff(second, 
TIMEFROMPARTS ( Start_hour, Start_minute, Start_second, 0, 0), 
TIMEFROMPARTS ( End_hour, End_minute, End_second, 0, 0))),0)
) As varchar)
+ 
':'
+
Cast
(
Datepart
(
second,
DATEADD(second,sum(datediff(second, 
TIMEFROMPARTS ( Start_hour, Start_minute, Start_second, 0, 0), 
TIMEFROMPARTS ( End_hour, End_minute, End_second, 0, 0))),0)
) As varchar) as result
from minsec
```